# Python - LinkedList confusion

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None    

    def insert_at_end(self,data):   >>> this function is working
        print('self.head: ', self.head)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data, None)
            return
        
        itr = self.head

        while itr.next != None:
            itr = itr.next

        itr.next = Node(data, None)
```

```
def insert_at_end(self,data):   >>> this function is NOT working
    n = self.head
    node = Node(data, None)
    if n is None:
        n = node
        return
    
    while n.next != None:
        n = n.next
    n.next = node
```

When I add a node at end, the function which is not working gives me an empty list but the function which is working gives me a list.  I think I am missing a basic point but unable to understand.  I am new to Python and learning DSA.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ll = LinkedList()
    ll.insert_at_end(100)
    ll.insert_at_end(101)
    ll.print_ll()
```

The working function gave me 100-->101-->
The non working function gave me empty linked list.

Below is the print function which I used in both cases.

```
    def print_ll(self):
        if self.head == None:
            print("Empty Linked List")
            return

        n = self.head
        strll = ''
        
        while n != None:
            strll += str(n.data) + '-->'
            print("linkedlist: ", strll)

            n = n.next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Just a minor nit.  Should be ```while n.next is not None:```

Comment: You're never setting self.head in your broken code.  The linked list will always be empty if the head isn't set.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you have is that:

```
n = self.head
n = node
```

Isn't the same thing as:

```
self.head = node
```

The first version just assigns two different values to the same local variable `n`, while the second modifies the `head` attribute of `self` in a way that will persist outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Blckknght has nicely [identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77682379/15261315) the problem with your code, but you can also make things easier on yourself (and improve performance) by storing the *last* element in your list along with the head.

You'll probably also find it useful to implement `__iter__` for your linked list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None    
        self.last = None

    def insert_at_end(self, data):   
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
            self.last = self.head
            return
        
        n = Node(data)
        self.last.next = n
        self.last = n

    def __iter__(self):
        itr = self.head
        while itr != None:
            yield itr.data
            itr = itr.next
```

With `__iter__` then you can implement `__str__` with something like:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return ' --> '.join(str(x) for x in self)
```